# HTML: Why is Div is not in Top Corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got 2 div in-line to each other.
If the second div is 2 lines long, the first div is no longer in the top corner...

Why is that?

EDIT: Why does div1 automatically vertical-align when the second div has 1 line but doesn't when it has 2 or more lines?

Check http://jsfiddle.net/d5Z6V/354/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">Not in top corner</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div>asd</div>
        <div>asd</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">In top corner</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div>asd</div>
    </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Rule one for anything, anywhere with an ID is that ID's need to be unique. With HTML if you have duplicate ID's use a class instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this isn't related to my issue.

Comment: Which is why it is a comment and not an answer. Step one for producing reliable results is to to produce code that sticks to the basic rules and standards. You know it is incorrect, but you do it anyway!!

Comment: In answer to the second question: inspecting the elements with Firebug, the default vertical-alignment is `baseline` which is why the bottom of the text in each of the elements is aligned. Firebug (or developer tools in Chrome) is very handy for this type of debugging/investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to vertically align it to top like this:

```css
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">Not in top corner</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div>asd</div>
        <div>asd</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">In top corner</div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div>asd</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does div1 automatically vertical-align when the second div has 1 line but doesn't when it has 2 or more lines?

Comment: @rainingchain All the `<div>`'s have a default `vertical-align` value of `baseline` which is why their bottoms are aligned with the baseline of the parent element. You can read more related to this over here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 0):

add vertical-align:top; to #div1